# Spacy.io Entity Linker "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)"

Tags: python-3.6, spacy

I have being trying to use Spacy.io's Wikipedia Entity Linker posted [here](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/master/nel-wikipedia).

When running "wikidata_train_entity_linker.py" I got the following error at the 3rd epoch.

I need help understanding why I am getting the error below. I googled and the [only mention of a similar problem](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4984) did not include a solution.

```
2020-09-03 17:54:31,725 - INFO - entity_linker_evaluation - Counts: {'EVENT': 2409, 'GPE': 16137, 'NORP': 2601, 'ORG': 12739, 'PERSON': 23443}
2020-09-03 17:54:31,725 - INFO - entity_linker_evaluation - Random: F-score = 0.331 | Recall = 0.199 | Precision = 0.983 | F-score by label = {'EVENT': 0.9166104742638795, 'GPE': 0.5135877024430415, 'NORP': 0.2743334404111789, 'ORG': 0.2596817157297999, 'PERSON': 0.11490371085112372}
2020-09-03 17:54:31,725 - INFO - entity_linker_evaluation - Prior: F-score = 0.331 | Recall = 0.199 | Precision = 0.983 | F-score by label = {'EVENT': 0.9166104742638795, 'GPE': 0.5135877024430415, 'NORP': 0.2743334404111789, 'ORG': 0.2596817157297999, 'PERSON': 0.11490371085112372}
2020-09-03 17:54:31,725 - INFO - entity_linker_evaluation - Oracle: F-score = 0.332 | Recall = 0.199 | Precision = 1.0 | F-score by label = {'EVENT': 0.91681654676259, 'GPE': 0.5161379310344828, 'NORP': 0.2820343461030383, 'ORG': 0.2596994535519126, 'PERSON': 0.11490833065294308}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wikidata_train_entity_linker.py", line 226, in <module>
    plac.call(main)
  File "/Users/eliranboraks/opt/anaconda3/envs/spacy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 328, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "/Users/eliranboraks/opt/anaconda3/envs/spacy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 207, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File "wikidata_train_entity_linker.py", line 172, in main
    docs, golds = zip(*train_batch)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

The command I used is `python3 wikidata_train_entity_linker.py -o output_lt_2m_model -l "FAC,LOC,PRODUCT,WORK_OF_ART,LAW,LANGUAGE,DATE,TIME,PERCENT,MONEY,QUANTITY,ORDINAL,CARDINAL" -t 500000 -d 50000 output_lt_2m`

The knowledge base directory was created successfully.

```
2020-09-03 12:13:02,283 - INFO - train_descriptions - Trained entity descriptions on 2155 (non-unique) descriptions across 5 epochs
2020-09-03 12:13:02,283 - INFO - train_descriptions - Final loss: 0.8585907478066995
2020-09-03 12:13:02,283 - INFO - kb_creator - Getting entity embeddings
2020-09-03 12:13:02,535 - INFO - train_descriptions - Encoded: 431 entities
2020-09-03 12:13:02,535 - INFO - kb_creator - Adding 431 entities
2020-09-03 12:13:02,544 - INFO - kb_creator - Adding aliases from Wikipedia and Wikidata
2020-09-03 12:13:02,544 - INFO - kb_creator - Adding WP aliases
2020-09-03 12:13:02,651 - INFO - __main__ - kb entities: 431
2020-09-03 12:13:02,651 - INFO - __main__ - kb aliases: 326
2020-09-03 12:13:05,640 - INFO - __main__ - Done!
```

Environment:
MacOS Catalina
Python 3.6
Spacy.io 2.3.2
Platform: Darwin-19.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that for a certain training batch, the algorithm couldn't find appropriate gold links to train on. I'm afraid you'll have to dig a bit into the code and your data to see what is going on. It looks like you have a relatively small KB. You can only have gold links if you have an NER in the pipeline that hits entries from that KB. If that doesn't happen, the EL algorithm doesn't have any data to work with, and throws this (unfortunately quite ugly) error.

You could try moving [this line](https://github.com/explosion/projects/blob/master/nel-wikipedia/wikidata_train_entity_linker.py#L172)

```
docs, golds = zip(*train_batch)
```

to directly below it, within the `try` block. Then the error should be logged, but hopefully the training will continue. That will show you whether the problem is just within that one training batch, or more general.

Comment: You very much Sofie. Follow-up question. From your answer, I understand that my problem is that I have only 431 entities in the KB. Here is what I got from the pre-train output. 

Can you help me understand why I have so few entities in the KB if I have 2M gold entities?

Commend used: `python3 wikidata_pretrain_kb.py -lt 2000000 -lp 200000 -lw 300000 -f 4 -a 10 latest-all.json.bz2 enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2 output_lt_2m en_core_web_lg`

Comment: I ran the `wikidata_pretrain_kb.py` on 50M articles and got 79936 entities in the KB. But, I am still getting `Error getting train batch:not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)` I have the offensive line wrap with try clause to keep the training running.

Comment: So is the problem just within that one batch? If so, that just means that there are no relevant entities in that batch, and it's fine to skip it.

Comment: yes, I think the problem is with one batch, adding the try-catch kept the training running. But now I am facing a new problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792296/spacy-io-wikipedia-entity-linker-results-nlp-model-have-no-kb-entities